# Unresolved issues with Eclipse in windows 7

Tags: c++

I upgraded my eclipse (cpp neon 2) and now I am getting an error every time I try to run my program. Been trying to fix this for couple hours but now I am running out of ideas how to fix it. I've already tried fixes from the google search but so far none have fixed it for me. I am using windows 7 and Cygwin as the compiler.

The errors I am getting are:

```
''Unresolved inclusion: <iostream>''
''Unresolved inclusion: <stdio.h>''
''Symbol 'cout' could not be resolved''
''Symbol 'std' could not be resolved''
```

my code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    int data[10];
    int dataatrec[10],c,c1,c2,c3,i;

    cout<<"Enter 4 bits of data one by one\n";
    cin>>data[0];
    cin>>data[1];
    cin>>data[2];
    cin>>data[4];

    data[6]=data[0]^data[2]^data[4];
    data[5]=data[0]^data[1]^data[4];
    data[3]=data[0]^data[1]^data[2];

    cout<<"\nEncoded data is\n";
    for(i=0;i<7;i++)
        cout<<data[i];

    cout<<"\n\nEnter received data bits one by one\n";
    for(i=0;i<7;i++)
        cin>>dataatrec[i];

    c1=dataatrec[6]^dataatrec[4]^dataatrec[2]^dataatrec[0];
    c2=dataatrec[5]^dataatrec[4]^dataatrec[1]^dataatrec[0];
    c3=dataatrec[3]^dataatrec[2]^dataatrec[1]^dataatrec[0];
    c=c3*4+c2*2+c1 ;

    if(c==0) {
        cout<<"\nNo error while transmission of data\n";
    }
    else {
        cout<<"\nError on position "<<c;

        cout<<"\nData sent : ";
        for(i=0;i<7;i++)
            cout<<data[i];

        cout<<"\nData received : ";
        for(i=0;i<7;i++)
            cout<<dataatrec[i];

        cout<<"\nCorrect message is\n";

        if(dataatrec[7-c]==0)
            dataatrec[7-c]=1;
        else
             dataatrec[7-c]=0;
        for (i=0;i<7;i++) {
            cout<<dataatrec[i];
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

[image: Folders]

Comment: Did you try to right-click the project - Index - Re-Resolve Unresolved Includes or the other options there?

Comment: Yes, nothing changes